# jQuery Deferred $.when callback to early

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

When using the jQuery Deferred class for loading modules, i get some weird behavior. The Callback for the completed loading queue writing "All modules loaded" is fired before the queue is finished. 
Is my usage of the deferred pattern wrong?

```
var ModuleMgr = {
    [...]
loadModule: function(name){
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        var module = ModuleMgr.getModuleByName(name);
        module.init(function(result){
            deferred.resolve(1);
        });
        return deferred;
    },

    loadAll: function(onReady, onError){
            var self = ModuleMgr;
        var promises = [];
        for ( var current in self.needLoading ){
            var module_name = self.needLoading.pop();
            try{
                var d = self.loadModule(module_name);
                promises.push(d.promise());
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log('Failed to load module' +module_name);
                self.needLoading.push(module_name);
                setTimeout(self.loadAll, 2000); // Try again
            }
        }

        $.when.apply(null, promises).then(
            function(status){
            console.log('All Modules loaded');
        }, function(status){
            console.log('Error happended: '+ status);
        }, function(status){
            console.log('Status'+ status);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please show how `.loadModule` and `.loadAll` are actually invoked - maybe you're not allowing `loadModule` time for every module load request to be added before it's called, so it doesn't know there's more modules to come?

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer, however your looping construct is rather wierd. `for in` then `pop`?

Comment: @plalx, Yes, that was one issue. The modules are now all invoked. I will test the deferred pattern with some timeouts to see if it works correctly. Thanks!